# Missing database script "Create_SenseNet_Database.sql" at How to set up development environment(sensenet)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sensenet

I am following the steps provided at the link http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_set_up_development_environment to set up the development environment.
I have downloaded the latest zip present at the following link http://sensenet.codeplex.com/
But I am unable to find **Create_SenseNet_Database.sql** in the latest zip downloaded from the http://sensenet.codeplex.com/. Please check this link http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_set_up_development_environment#8._Prepare_db_scripts
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the source package, not the binary? The big Download button on the right (on the codeplex page) gives you the _binary_ package, but the wiki article you linked to assumes you have the _source package_. That is accessible from the Downloads menu and its name is "sensenet654-community-source" (the second one in the list).

Comment: Thank you @MiklosToth. I have downloaded the _binary_ package only. I have found _sensenet654-community-source_ under downloads as you mentioned in above comment.